# Compare and match last part of URL with and accented/unaccented input value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I want to match the last part of the **site url** with an **input value**. This string starts with **#**.

The input value can **have accents or not**.

This is what I have right now:

```
  $(function () {
    var loc = window.location.href.split("#")[0]; // returns the full URL

    var href = location.href;
    var hrefM = href.match(/#([^\/]*)\/*$/)[1];
    var hreflocation = hrefM.replace(/-/g, " ").toProperCase();

    if (hreflocation) {
      $(".wpcf7-list-item :input[value= '" + hreflocation + "' ]").parent().addClass("active");
      $(".wpcf7-list-item :input[value= '" + hreflocation + "' ]").attr("checked",true);
    }
  });
```

It works fine when there are no accents.
Do you know how to adjust my `hrefM` so that although this word has no accents it is the same as an `input` with accents?

For example, this comparison doesn't work right now:

```
url hreflocation = "#produccio"
<input value="producció">
```

But this comparison works well:

```
url hreflocation = "#produccio"
<input value="produccio">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I'd like to point out a few things.

1. The text after the # in the URL is called the hash, and you can access it with `location.hash`.
2. `<String>.toProperCase` is not a function.
3. You cannot match all possible latin diacritics and variations in an attribute selector.

You can instead do:

```js
$(function() {
  if (location.hash) {
    const hash = location.hash.substring(1).replaceAll('-', ' ');
    const matchedInput = $(".wpcf7-list-item input").toArray()
      .find(input => input.value.normalize('NFKD').replace(/\p{Diacritic}/gu, '') == hash);
  }
});
```

- `hash` takes the location hash, removes the `#`, and converts all `-` to
- `$(".wpcf7-list-item input").toArray()` selects all input elements inside the `.wpcf7-list-item` and converts them to an array (to allow you to process them with JavaScript)
- `.find` looks for an element in the array whose value, when normalized and stripped of diacritics, is equal to `hash`

You can then use `$(matchedInput)` however you want. If you instead want an array of matched inputs, you can replace `find` with `filter`.

Comment: I don't understand, doing a simple `console.log(matchedInput)` returns `undefined` :/ how can I used it however I want?

Comment: @z-1881 well are you sure the `input` elements are inside `.wpcf7-list-item`? see what `$(".wpcf7-list-item input")` gives you

Comment: yes, every `input` is inside `.wpcf7-list-item`, `console.log(matchedInput)` still returns `undefined`

Comment: @z-1881 i changed it to `/gu`, see if that works

Comment: I get the same `undefined` :/

Comment: just debug --- `console.log($(".wpcf7-list-item input").toArray(), $(".wpcf7-list-item input").toArray().map(input => input.value.normalize('NFKD').replace(/\p{Diacritic}/gu, '')))`

Comment: I see, it works, thank you